# How to bundle Kivy code in main.py

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to build a kivy app and I need to put my .py file and .kv file in a file called main.py. How do I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **embed** your *.kv file* in python like this

```
Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    ...

""")

class MyApp(App):
    ...
```

for more info click [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.builder.html?highlight=builder#module-kivy.lang.builder)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use Builder for this. [Docs](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=builder+kivy&oq=builder+kivy&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3393j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
The below code illustrate it.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<Root>:
    cols: 2
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 39/255., 174/255., 96/255.
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        text: "rgb: 39/255., 174/255., 96/255."
    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 39/255., 174/255., 96/255., 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        text: "rgba: 39/255., 174/255., 96/255., 1"
    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                hsv: 145/360., 77.6/100, 68.2/100
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        text: "hsv: 145/360., 77.6/100, 68.2/100"
    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#27ae60')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        text: "rgba: hex('#27ae60')"
""")


class Root(GridLayout):
    pass


class ColorusageApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     ColorusageApp().run()
```